# What does across mean?

Tags: transformer

What does across mean?

Does it mean between Phases A and C?

OR

Does it mean in phase A and on phase C?

[image]

Comment: Is this a technical question or an English understanding question?

Comment: Across also means between in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, "across" means "between". In other words you connect one end of the impedance to phase A and the other to phase C.

I don't know what you mean by "in phase A and on phase C", but whatever that means, it isn't the correct interpretation.